# getting the exception "ClassNotFoundException" while connectivity on laptop whose configuration is processor core 2duo and os is window 7 32 bit

Tags: jdbc

I have successfully executed my program of jdbc (with oracle 10g and java 1.7) on my pc whose configuration is following: processor pentium 4 and os is windows xp.

I have done the following steps for connectivity

Click Start, point to Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Data Sources(ODBC).

- Click the System DSN tab, and then click Add.
- Click the database driver that corresponds with the database type to which you are connecting, and then click Finish.
- Type the data source name. Make sure that you choose a name that you can remember. You will need to use this name later.
- Click Select.
- Click the correct database, and then click OK.
- Click OK, and then click OK.

The program is given below

```java
import java.sql.*;
class connection
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException

    {

     Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
     Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:orajdbc", "system", "123456");
     Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from student");
     while(rs.next())
      {
         System.out.println("Roll no="+ rs.getString(1));    
         System.out.println("Name=" + rs.getString(2));
      }

   }
}
```

But I am not able to do the same on my laptop whose configuration is processor core 2duo and os is window 7 32 bit I am getting the exception of `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: 1) Which Java version? The `JdbcOdbcDriver` is no longer supported with Java 8, 2) to connect to Oracle you should use the Oracle JDBC driver instead.

Comment: Have your application display the value returned by `System.getProperty("java.version")`. If it starts with "1.8" then the JDBC-ODBC Bridge is not available (per. comment #1 from @MarkRotteveel, above).

Comment: i am using java 1.7 version.